# Django view auto-Posting on load

Tags: python, html, django, post

I have a simple `ModelForm` that submits the form once the page loads. I need the form to stop submitting on load so I can correctly pass a template value to it.

**Any idea on how to stop the page from submitting on load?**

Below is the code in question.

Page HTML:

```
    {% extends "stamped/home.html" %}
    {% block results %}
    <h2>Let The world know what you think!</h2> 
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table>
            {{ form.as_table }}
        </table>
        <input id="upload_submit" type="submit" value="Stamp it!">
    </form>
    {% endblock %}
```

Django View:

```
    @login_required
    def make_comment(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            print request.POST
            form = CommentForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                comment = form.save(commit=False)
                comment.user = request.user
                comment.save()
                # render?
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/results/', {
                    'restaurant': get_object_or_404(
                                                    Restaurant, 
                                                    name=request.POST['name'], 
                                                    address=request.POST['address']
                                                    )
                    })
            else:
                form = CommentForm()
            return render(request, 'stamped/comment.html', {'form': form}

    )
```

HTML the template is extending:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- stamped home page -->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Stamped</title>
    <link type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div id="navi">
        <div id="navi_elements">
          <ul>
          <li class="navi_text"><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Stamped Home</a></li>
          {% if user.is_authenticated %}
          <li class="navi_text"><a href="{% url 'logout_view' %}">Logout</a></li>
          {% else %}
          <li class="navi_text"><a href="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">Login</a></li>
          {% endif %}
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="panel">
      <input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50">
    </div>

    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <div id="results">{% block results %}{% endblock %}</div>
    {% if top_choices %}  
    <div id='feed_stream'>
    {% for r in top_choices %}
      <div class='top_choice_div'>
        <ul class='top_choice_list'>
          {% for i in r %}
          {% if forloop.first %}
          <li class="choice_cat_name"> {{ i.category }}</li>
          {% endif %}
          <li>{{ i.name }} Rating: {{ i.rating }}</li>
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
      <div id='recently_added_Restaurants'>
        <ul id='rar_list'>
          {% for i in recently_added_Restaurants %}
          {% if forloop.first %}
          <li id="rar_name">Recently Added Restaurants</li>
          {% endif %}
          <li>{{ i.name }} Rating: {{ i.rating }}</li>
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id='recent_reviews'>
        <ul id='rr_list'>
          {% for i in recent_reviews %}
          {% if forloop.first %}
          <li id="rr_name">Recent Reviews</li>
          {% endif %}
          <li>{{ i.restaurant }} Rating: {{ i.rating }}</li>
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endif %}  
  </body>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/map.js"></script>
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/home_jquery.js"></script>
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery_cookie/jquery.cookie.js"></script>

</html>
```

JS:

home_jq.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //initialize main map
    $(google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize));

    $(".top_choice_list").selectable();

});
```

Map.js:

```
//intialize main map
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    //set lat long for nyc 
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.7200, -73.9900),
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

  var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
  new google.maps.LatLng(40.7200, -74.0000),
  new google.maps.LatLng(40.7200, -73.9000));

  var options = {
  bounds: defaultBounds,
  types: ['establishment'],
  //rescrict results to US
  componentRestrictions: {country: 'US'}
  };


  var input = (document.getElementById('searchTextField'));
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

  autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    //remove any pervious info on the map (if there is any) to get ready for a new query
    infowindow.close();
    marker.setVisible(false);
    input.className = '';
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    if (!place.geometry) {
      // Inform the user that the place was not found and return.
      input.className = 'notfound';
      return;
    }

    // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
      map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
      map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
    }
    marker.setIcon(/** @type {google.maps.Icon} */({
      url: place.icon,
      size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35)
    }));
    marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
    marker.setVisible(true);

    var address = '';
    if (place.address_components) {
      address = [
        (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
        (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
        (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
      ].join(' ');
    }

    infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);

    //var output_list = [place.name, address];


    //handle CSRF 

    //send map change to home_jQuery.js
/*    var csrftoken = $.cookie('csrftoken'); 
    var send_data = { 'name': place.name, 'address': address};
    $.post( '/results/', send_data, function (response){
        alert(response); 
        return send_data;

    } );*/

    var send_data = { 'name': place.name, 'address': address};

    var csrftoken = $.cookie('csrftoken'); 

    function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
    } 

    $.ajaxSetup({
        crossDomain: false, // obviates need for sameOrigin test
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type)) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
            }
        }
    });

    $.ajax({ url: '/results/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: send_data,
        success: function(response) {
          console.log("everything worked!");
          $("#results").html(response);
        },
        error: function(obj, status, err) { alert(err); console.log(err); }
      });




  });

}
```

Comment: Show us your javascript, please

Comment: @limelights Updated above :)

Comment: @limelights I just tried commenting out all of my JS in case it was causing the double posting, but it still is.

Answer (score 0):

In your document `ready` function, you call:

```
$(google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize));
```

This calls your `initialize()` function when the window is loaded.  At the beginning of your `initialize()` function you call:

```
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
```

This is incorrect, `Autocomplete()` requires two arguments: see [Adding Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#adding_autocomplete) in the documentation.

At the very end of the `initialize()` function you call:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function()
```

which probably gets triggered because of the faulty `autocomplete` variable.  That invokes the following AJAX call which performs the POST:

```
$.ajax({ url: '/results/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: send_data,
    success: function(response) {
      $('#results').html(response);
    },
    error: function(obj, status, err) { alert(err); console.log(err); }
  });
```

...so the AJAX POST is always called when the window is loaded.

Comment: Hey brent thanks for answering. While that function is in the initialize event, the `ajax post` is in `google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() { ...` within the initialize function. It was my understanding that this would only execute on `place_changed` after an `autocomplete` despite the initialized being called on window load. Is that not the case?

Comment: You're right, see my update.  I think it's because the `autocomplete` variable isn't being set correctly.

Comment: I know it cant be the ajax post because if it was I would see the post in the console and see `alert(csrftoken);` I tried your suggestion anyway, incase you still were right but it didnt stop the double posting. Any idea what else it could be?

Comment: You can also see from my comment to @limelight that I tried removing all of the js in my file to see if that stopped the double posting. It didnt.

Comment: Did you fix `Autocomplete()` so it has an `options` argument?

Comment: I believe I fixed `autocomplete()`. Check out my fix in the updated the `map.js` code above. Let me know if you think its correct.

Comment: As far as I know, the only ways to submit a form are when the Submit button is clicked or a Javascript `submit()` function is called.  Check your JS for any hidden functions because nothing above shows what is causing the auto submit.